# What is the meaning of "process" here?

Tags: meaning

The piece of text is:

"A newsmobile from WGAN‑TV pulled up. One of the guys got out, patting
his *process* neatly into place, and jawed with a cop. The cop pointed across the
road. The guy with the *process* went back to the newsmobile, and two more guys
got out and started unloading camera equipment."

Comment: You haven't include a source for this quote, so I've downvoted.

Comment: It's his hair. I suspect the guy with the obvious hair transplant or wig (because that is what it is) is the person who appears in front of the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conking process is a method of straightening afro hair using lye. The hairstyle was known as a "conk" or a "process".

In the 1940s and 50s nearly all African American women, and many African American men straightened their hair.  Some used hot straightening irons, but hair could also be straightened by chemicals. The hairstyles from chemically straightened hair were seen as flamboyant or grand.  Many music stars such as Chuck Berry or Little Richard had processes.

This use of the noun "process" is now very rare, as this hairstyle has gone out of fashion.

Comment: If you really want to stick it to people who ask questions without providing sources, stop providing your excellent answers. I mostly only answer questions that I'm happy to upvote.